# Why does the following code not import the correct format of the cells?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the following code:

```
   var importRangeUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/...";
  var importRangeA1 = "Evaluation!A1:AX80";

  var importedValues = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(importRangeUrl).getRange(importRangeA1).getDisplayValues();

  var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Separate Evaluation Spreadsheet");
  var ss = newSheet.getSheetByName(newSheet.getSheets()[0].getName());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

  ss.getRange('A1').activate();
  ss.getRange(1, 1, importedValues.length, importedValues[0].length).setValues(importedValues);

 chart = chart.modify()
  .asComboChart()
  .addRange(ss.getRange('B48:AX77'))
  .addRange(ss.getRange('B78:AX78'))
  .addRange(ss.getRange('B40:AX40'))
  .setMergeStrategy(Charts.ChartMergeStrategy.MERGE_ROWS)
  .setTransposeRowsAndColumns(true)
  .setNumHeaders(1)
  .setHiddenDimensionStrategy(Charts.ChartHiddenDimensionStrategy.IGNORE_BOTH)
  .setOption('bubble.stroke', '#000000')
  .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain', true)
  .setOption('isStacked', 'absolute')
  .setOption('height', 505)
  .setOption('width', 817)
  .setPosition(1, 3, 116, 4)
  .build(); 
  ss.insertChart(chart);
};
```

The code should open a new spreadsheet and import the values via URL from another table and create a column chart in the new spreadsheet.(In the original sheet there is already an existing chart, that is why I use chart.modify)  This would work perfectly, but the code inserts the values in a new format in the new spreadsheet (36.9 instead of 36,9 (. instead of ,) for example), so the column chart is empty and I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'modify' of undefined (row 16, Datei "Makros") (chart = chart.modify()). 
**For example: in the original sheet there is a 36,9 and in the new sheet it is 36.9, so a point instead of a commata (. instead of ,).** This causes my error! What do I have to add to the code or change that this does not happen?

Comment: did you check the locale settings of your new spreadsheet ? The decimal separator changes according to this setting.

Comment: what dou you mean with local settings and where does the decimal separator get changed? Could you be more precise pls.

Comment: where is the change of the decimal separator?

Comment: linked with language settings

Answer (score 0):

Your new Spreadsheet is being created by another locale format that uses `.`, instead of `,` for decimal numbers. You can change it using the GUI following [these steps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113082/setting-up-decimal-separator-thousand-separator-and-date-in-google-spreadsheets) or doing it programmatically using the [`.setSpreadsheetLocale(locale)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html#setSpreadsheetLocale(String)) method from the [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.html). For example:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().setSpreadsheetLocale("es_VE")
```

[HERE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103958/change-google-sheets-default-date-format-with-other-locale/106243#106243) you can see a format's list from a lot of countries.

### EDIT

In your code, use it after creating the new Spreadsheet:

```
var newSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Separate Evaluation Spreadsheet");
// The format I'm using is an example, you can use any format you want
newSheet.setSpreadsheetLocale("es_VE");
```

Comment: can you show me how to implement it in my code? in which step?

Comment: ok! I edited my answer to show you where to use it. I hope now it's better explained